# Split Frame Into Columns

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a code where I am finding the correlation within columns of my data and printing the result as a data frame

```
correlation= Answer0.corr()

corr_self=(correlation.where(numpy.triu(numpy.ones(correlation.shape),k=3).astype(numpy.bool)).stack()
        .sort_values(ascending=False))
frame_5=corr_self.to_frame()
```

[image: Returns something like this]

How can I seperate that frame into three diff columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `reset_index` it should convert all index to columns.